# Sitecore SXA : Your site has been exported in Wireframe mode

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-sxa

Sitecore SXA : Your site has been exported in Wireframe mode. This mode does not reflect your site’s look and feel and may cause problems for importing and editing.

When i try to export, Site themes getting above error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens if you export when your View mode is set to wireframe. You need to select Experience Accelerator ribbon > View Mode > Selected Theme. You may need to set a theme first using Experience Accelerator ribbon > Theme.

See [The View Modes for SXA 1.9](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/the-view-modes.html) for the full background.